# How to visualise the curve $y=\ln x$ rotating around its $y$-axis

Tags: integration, rotations

> Let the area limited by the curve $y=\ln x$, the line $x=e$ and the $x$-axis rotate around the $y$-axis. Decide the volume of the resulting rotational body.

First thing, I drew the graph:

[image]

But then I got stuck on how to imagine/visualise the curve rotating around its $y$-axis. How should I think when visualising the function $lnx$ rotating around its $y$-axis?

EDIT: 
In the comment section it was written that "if you rotate the rectangle $[0,e]×[0,1]$, it makes a cylinder which volume is easy to compute", but I am not very familiar with the notation for $[0,e]×[0,1]$.

Comment: If you're rotating around the $y$-axis, it should be $\int\pi x^2\,\mathrm{d}y$

Comment: Correct, I will edit this mistake.

Comment: Hint: if you rotate the rectangle $[0, e]\times [0, 1]$, it makes a cylinder which volume is easy to compute. Remove from this volume the part obtained by rotating the area between the $y$ axis and the $ln$ curve.

Comment: @Gribouillis I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with your notatation for $[0,e]\times[0,1]$, is it possible for you to word this in another way? Or maybe draw what you mean and insert a photo of it as a comment?

Comment: It is the rectangle where $x$ varies from $0$ to $e$, and $y$ varies from $0$ to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the intersection of $e^y$ and $e$ and that is $y = 1$

Inner Radius $= e^{y}$ and Outer Radius $= e$

[image]

Then the area of the surface rotating $y = \ln x$ around y axis

$$V = \int_{0}^{1} \pi (e^2-e^{2y})dy = \pi(e^2y - \pi\frac{e^{2y}}{2})|_{0}^{1} = (\pi e^2 - 0) - (\frac{\pi e^2}{2} -1) = \frac{\pi (e^2+1)}{2}$$

Comment: The correct answer according to the book is $\pi(e^2+1)/2$ v.u., which is not equal to $\pi e^2/2$ v.u.. (Your integral appears to be correctly computed).

Comment: But the integration is not the problem, I have problem visualising the integral itself

Comment: (But that is not to say that your integral is correct)

Comment: I got it. It is the area between y = lnx , x= e and y = 0.  Now you get the answer.  Thanks for correcting I got misled by your diagram.

Comment: See the edit for the correct answer

Comment: I don't really understand the following. You get the integral $\int_0^1 dy e^2\pi$ substracted by the integral $\int_0^1 dy e^{2y}\pi$, but why do you use the integral $\int_0^1 dy e^2\pi$?

Comment: I have given a graphic illustration of the outer radius and inner radius and the area that is being rotated around y axis shaded outside. Let me know if you still need explanation

Comment: Now I think I get it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

take a look here with wolfy for $$f=log(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+log%28%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%5E.5%29

Answer (score 0):

*Here I (the OP) will add my solution to the problem.*

Think of it like follows. If the integral $\int_0^1 dy \;\pi (e)^2$ represents the area of

[image]

And the integral $\int_0^1 dy \;\pi (e^y)^2$ represents the area of

[image]

Then the area of

[image]

is computed like this:

$$\int_0^1 dy \;\pi (e)^2-\int_0^1 dy \;\pi (e^y)^2=\int_0^1 dy \;\pi(e^2-e^{2y})$$

And this integral gives you the answer $\frac{\pi (e^2+1)}{2} \text{v.u.}$